# Compiler warnings from unused ports due to "generate" conditions

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, compiler-warnings

I use "generate" to create different flows inside modules, and sometimes ports are used unly in some cases. For example:

```
module addthese (a, b, c, d);
input [7:0] a, b, c;
output [9:0] d;

parameter addOnlyAandB = "NO";

generate
    if (addOnlyAandB == "YES") begin : add_only_a_and_b
        always @*
            d <= a + b;
    end else begin : add_a_b_and_c
        always @*
            d <= a + b + c;
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Passing "YES" in parameter addOnlyAandB causes input c to be ignored. This causes the compiler to generate a bunch of warnings (one per bit of c), and rightfully so, that input c is redundant and removed.

```
[EFX-0200 WARNING] Removing redundant signal : c[7]. (C:\path\file.v:49)
```

This is one of these cases to "just ignore the warnings" because addOnlyAandB must clearly have been set to "YES" intentionally. But ignoring warnings is a bad thing to do as it becomes easy to not see some important warning hiding among the many "benign ones" and something will eventually fail unexpectedly.

Can somehow a port be deleted depending on a genvar?

What is the right way to build this function so that there are no such warnings?
Of course the real one is very large with many possible combinations of many parameters and generate blocks, so writing one fuction for each combination is out of the question.

Thank you,

Bruno

Comment: RTL synthesis tools remove unused logic. That is what they do, and they should tell you about it.  Top of the line linting tools give the user filters to select which warnings to show or not show.

Comment: Hi Ilia, 
Assigning to something like "unused_ok", as you suspected, just gets additional warnings issued for "unused_ok" in addition to the ones for "c".

Adjusting widths with parameters is nice & easy for this little example, but the real code has many "optional" ports with several different parameters which may or may not cause ports to become unused. So it becomes impractical to use parameterized widths for other things as the number of possible combinations of parameters is very large.

I'd be very happy to hear other suggestions.

Thank you very much for pitching in, appreciated.

Comment: Use grep -v <SOMETHING TO FILTER> to remove lines from the log file.

Answer (score 0):

A number of ports cannot be controlled via genvars. But in SystemVerilog you can control sizes of arrays. For example,

```
module addthese#(N = 2) (input logic [7:0] args[N], output logic [9:0] d);

  if (N == 2) begin : add_only_a_and_b
        always @*
          d = args[0] + args[1];
  end else if (N == 3) begin : add_a_b_and_c
        always @*
          d = args[0] + args[1] + args[2];   
endmodule
```

An example of instantiation:

```
module tb();
  logic [7:0] a, b, c;
  logic [9:0] d1, d2;
    
  addthese add2('{a,b}, d1);
  addthese #(3) add3('{a,b,c}, d2);
  
endmodule
```

Another possibility is to parameterize your module with a type:

```
module addthese#(type A = int, N = 2) (input A args, output logic [9:0] d);

  if (N == 2) begin : add_only_a_and_b
        always @*
          d = args.a + args.b;
  end else if (N == 3) begin : add_a_b_and_c
        always @*
          d = args.a + args.b + args.c; 
  end
endmodule

module tb();
  typedef  struct  {
     logic[7:0] a,b;
  } twoArgs_t;
  typedef  struct {
    logic[7:0] a,b,c;
  } threeArgs_t;
  twoArgs_t twoArgs;
  threeArgs_t threeArgs;

  logic [9:0] d1, d2;
    
  addthese #(twoArgs_t, 2) add2(twoArgs, d1);
  addthese #(threeArgs_t, 3) add3(threeArgs, d2);
  
endmodule
```

Comment: That's right, I'd forgotten about that!
This doesn't fully resolve the issue because some named ports still will not be used at all, but it can make the number of warnings shrink. Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to use \`ifdef .. \`endif instead of genvars.

Comment: I cannot use `ifdef because of the scope of `define'd symbols. This module gets instantiated multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: In this case you have no choice. The number of ports in all instances must be the same. But, as I said you can use array with different sizes, or in more general case, you can parameterize your module with a different type. I added such an example to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could add something like "assign unused_ok = c;" to the Yes section, so that you sidestep this warning, but this might generate other warnings (or linting violations) down the line. You could also re-code this, so that, instead of three separate inputs, you get an array of inputs, whose length is controlled by a parameter -- something like:

```
parameter WIDTH = 3;
input [WIDTH-1:0][7:0] abc_list;
```

Then, you can build a single parametric always block, and leave no unused inputs.

Comment: To clarify: the purpose of the unused_ok approach is not necessarily to eliminate warnings, but to ensure that the warnings come for something you know you can ignore. Regarding your other comment: if your module has multiple optional ports, corresponding to multiple different functionalities, which you cannot easily capture with a simple always block, then it might be a good idea to either split it into multiple different modules, or use verilog configs and compile different versions of the same module in different libraries.